# how to calculate the ndvi % greater than 0.5 in a particular zone and also cloud percentage

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ndvi

i have a problem whem i am working to calculate the ndvi from landsat sattellite of rainy season i have assumed the pixel value above 15000 are clouds and calculate NDVI.then i am assigning the clouds pixel in ndvi 1.

The main question is how to calculate zonal  min max value of ndvi and percentage of cloud and percentage of ndvi greater than 0.5 in a particular zone.(zone are the vilage boundary of District).
please help to solve this problem in arc gis

---

i have already calculated mean max and min value of ndvi but i want to calculate polygone(zone) wise NDVI >.5(%) and also same in clouds.

Answer (score 1):

1. NDVI value of 1 is a valid (if unlikely) case, you might consider another value to assign as denoting 'cloud'
2. If you are looking for [zonal statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000w8000000) then you could select those Cloud and NDVI>.5 and run them separately for your study area.
3. You may also be able to select the min and max from a clipped image using the [raster attribute table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t00000009000000).